# Riak Erlang module installation error

Tags: erlang, riak

I took the master branch for riak-erlang-client and called `make`

```
   ./rebar get-deps
==> meck (get-deps)
==> protobuffs (get-deps)
==> hamcrest (get-deps)
==> riak_pb (get-deps)
==> riak-erlang-client (get-deps)
./rebar compile
==> meck (pre_compile)
==> meck (compile)
==> protobuffs (pre_compile)
==> protobuffs (compile)
==> hamcrest (pre_compile)
==> hamcrest (compile)
==> hamcrest (post_compile)
==> riak_pb (pre_compile)
==> riak_pb (compile)
==> riak-erlang-client (compile)
raghuveer@ubuntu:~/erlang-git/riak-erlang-client$ erl -pa $PATH_TO_RIAKC/ebin $PATH_TO_RIAKC/deps/*/ebin
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> code:which(riakc_pb_socket).
non_existing
```

Also tried

`make clean && make all`

build went fine, but when i call

`./rebar install`

i see cannot be run on erlang-java-client directory. Fine so to check if the installation is already done i ran below :

```
/riak-erlang-client$ erl -pa $PATH_TO_RIAKC/ebin $PATH_TO_RIAKC/deps/*/ebin
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> code:which(riakc_pb_socket).
non_existing
```

What can i do to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `~/erlang-git/riak-erlang-client` directory, run this instead:

```
erl -pa ./ebin ./deps/*/ebin
```

The examples use the `$PATH_TO_RIAKC` environment variable to demonstrate that you must set this variable if you run `erl` from another location. Since the `.beam` files for the Erlang client and its dependencies are available, you don't need this env variable to be set.

Comment: In erl shell i ran `{ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start_link("127.0.0.1", 8087).` and got "Syntax error before : {" should i substitute for Pid, what should i put there ?

Comment: That syntax error was likely an unfinished command on the previous line in the shell.  Try running just `ok.` and then retry your command.